# Selecting every other number in int

Tags: c, long-integer

I am writing a program in which I am asking a user for long long int. After the user has provided me with a number, I want to add every other digit in that number, starting from the second digit. Now my question is, how can I select every other digit in long long int? (C language)

[image: Selecting every other digit in long long int]

Comment: Tell me a reason you cannot use modulo to extract  the digits for this.....

Comment: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Or use `sprintf` to convert the number to a string, and then add the digits.

Answer (score 2):

Given a integral type number `n`, `n % 100 / 10` will extract the second to last digit. This expression is a touchstone for your knowledge of operator precedence and associativity.

You'll need to use `n % 10` and `n / 10` to extract and subsequently remove the last digit if the number of digits in the number is even (search around on this site for adequate algorithms to count the number of digits in a number).

`n / 100` will remove the final two digits.

Put the above into a loop, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long real_Number,num,arr[100],count=0;
    scanf("%ld",&real_Number);
    do{
          if(real_Number>99)
          {
             num=real_Number%100;
             num=num/10;
             arr[count]=num;
             real_Number=real_Number/100;
           ++count;
           }
           if(real_Number<100)
           {
              arr[count]=real_Number/10;
              break;
           }
       }while(real_Number>=10);

}
```

> **Note** : The Digits stored in array are backward for example 123456 results in
>
> arr[0]=5, arr[1]=3 ,arr[2]=1;

To print:-

```
for(count; count>=0 ;count--)
{
    printf("%ld",arr[count]);
}
```